# Is ISO8601DateFormatter broken in iOS14 and MacOS 11?

Tags: swift, xcode, datetime, nsdateformatter, beta

I'm experimenting with the latest beta after WWDC.

`ISO8601DateFormatter().date(from:"2017-12-18T11:30:26.000Z")` should return a date. Instead it is returning nil. This worked in iOS 13.

I broke it down and tested it in Swift Playground. I'm working with Xcode Version 12.0 beta (12A6159)

```
let testString = "2017-12-18T11:30:26.000Z"
let testString2 = "2017-12-18"
let testFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
let testDate1 = testFormatter.date(from: testString)
let testDate2 = testFormatter.date(from: testString2)
```

`testDate1` and `testDate2` should be dates, they are nils.

`testFormatter` is partly functional. The line below returns the current date as a string as expected; "2020-06-27T18:53:39Z".

```
let testDate3 = testFormatter.string(from: Date())
```

Am I missing something here, or is this just an early beta bug? I have filed a Feedback with Apple, but I'm hoping someone here has an answer.

Comment: I strongly doubt that it works in iOS 13. By default fractional seconds (`.000`) are not considered and `testString2` doesn't work either with the default format options.

Comment: See[`formatOptions`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/iso8601dateformatter), e.g. [`withFractionalSeconds`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/iso8601dateformatter),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted doesn't work in iOS 13 as well.

Try the following:

```
let testString = "2017-12-18T11:30:26.000Z"
let testString2 = "2017-12-18"
let testFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
```

```
testFormatter.formatOptions = [
    .withFullDate,
    .withFullTime,
    .withFractionalSeconds,
]
let testDate1 = testFormatter.date(from: testString)
```

```
testFormatter.formatOptions = [.withFullDate]
let testDate2 = testFormatter.date(from: testString2)
```